# One dimensional affine map

Tags: linear-transformations

Why is $f(x) = mx$ a linear map in one dimension? Linear maps must satisfy $L(ab) = L(a)L(b)$, but in the above case, we would have $f(xy) = mxy \neq m^2xy = f(x)f(y)$. I'm probably being really dumb here, and there's something obvious I'm missing, but I wasn't really sure how to word my question in Google, and wasn't able to uncover my mistake.

Comment: Are you sure that's the definition of linear?

Comment: oh my god, I can't believe I've done this. haha, thank you =)